# How to pass LoginResult from facebook login to an Intent in Android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to build a sample Android application, that connects to Facebook SDK, Login to facebook and post a message on my wall.

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("manage_pages,publish_pages"));
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult result) {
                serialize_login sl = new serialize_login();
                sl.result=result;
                   Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,PublishMessage.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("LoginResult",sl);
                startActivity(myIntent);

            }
```

If the login is successful, I want to invoke another activity which would take care of the message posting. I need accessToken to accomplish that and I am trying to pass that to the Intent. Since the Intent would only accept String, I built a serializable class called `serialize_login`. At the receiving end , I do this

```
LoginResult lr = (LoginResult)myIntent.getExtras().getSerializable("result");
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newPostRequest(lr.getAccessToken(), pageID
                , null, new GraphRequest.Callback() {
```

I get the following exception.

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.facebook.login.LoginResult
                                                                                    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1364)
                                                                                    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
                                                                                    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
```

Can someone help? If serializing is not the right thing to do, how do I pass an object to an intent( other than a string)

Answer (score 1):

Facebook's [LoginResult](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LoginResult/) is a Java object which does not implement [Serializable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) interface, neither does it implement the [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) interface. 
What this means is that, you cannot pass it through an intent.

My suggestion is to highlight why you need to pass a LoginResult to the next activity and let's find a better way of retrieving that information you need without passing through an intent.

---

However, if  you're bent on doing it, even though I personally won't advise that you to, here's what you can do:

If you look at the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LoginResult/) of the LoginResult class here, you will see that you can get the `AccessToken`, `recentlyGrantedPermissions`, as well as `recentlyDeniedPermissions`.

Also, looking at the source code of [AccessToken](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/main/java/com/facebook/AccessToken.java), you will see that it implements [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html), which means you can pass the AccessToken via `intent.putExtra()`. Meaning you can do something like:

```
intent.putExtra("AccessToken", loginResult.getAccessToken());
```

The other methods `getRecentlyDeniedPermissions()` and `getRecentlyGrantedPermissions()` each return a [Set](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Set.html) containing Strings.

A set by itself cannot be passed via intent, because it implements neither Serializable nor Parcelable, you can wrap it around a [HashSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashSet.html) (which implements Serializable)

```
intent.putSerializable("RecentlyGrantedPermissions", new HashSet<>(loginResult.getRecentlyGrantedPermissions());
```

**There are two reasons why this is not recommended:**

1. You should always try to pass Parcelables instead of Serializables where possible, because of performance reasons.
2. This feels like too much of a hack. There is most likely a better way of doing what you want to do.